# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: maven, servlets, struts-1

Hi i'm creating a simple form and displaying their value in another jsp page using maven struts 1.3 dependencies but i m getting the following error

> HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /success.jsp at line 13

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /success.jsp at line 13

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /success.jsp at line 13

10: </head>
11: <body>
12: <h1>Congrats!!!</h1>
13: <bean:write name="loginForm" property="firstName" />
14: </body>
15: </html>
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean: "loginForm" in any scope
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
org.apache.jsp.success_jsp._jspService(success_jsp.java:147)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean: "loginForm" in any scope
org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.lookup(TagUtils.java:864)
org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.WriteTag.doStartTag(WriteTag.java:233)
org.apache.jsp.success_jsp._jspx_meth_bean_005fwrite_005f0(success_jsp.java:167)
org.apache.jsp.success_jsp._jspService(success_jsp.java:131)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

here is all of my code

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>StrutsWebApp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>StrutsWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>StrutsWebApp</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>LoginFormStruts</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
   </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

struts-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="loginForm" type="amit.forms.LoginForm" />
</form-beans>
<action-mappings>
    <action name="loginForm" path="/login"
        type="amit.action.LoginAction" scope="request"
        input="/login.jsp">
        <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp" redirect="true" />
    </action>
</action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

LoginAction.java

```
package amit.action;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class LoginAction extends Action {
@Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("hello");
        return mapping.findForward("success");

}

}
```

LoginForm.java

```
package amit.forms;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

public class LoginForm extends ActionForm {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String firstName = null;
private String lastName = null;
private String phoneNo = null;
private String zipCode = null;
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getPhoneNo() {
    return phoneNo;
}
public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
}
public String getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
}
public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
}
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<html:form action="/login" focus="firstName">
<table>
    <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><html:text property="firstName" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><html:text property="lastName" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Phone No:</td><td><html:text property="phoneNo" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Postal Code:</td><td><html:text property="zipCode" /></td></tr>      
    <tr><td colspan="2"><html:submit value="login" /></td></tr>
    </table>
</html:form>
</body>
</html>

}
```

success.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Congrats!!!</h1>
<bean:write name="loginForm" property="firstName" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just remove the

> scope="request"

from my struts-config.xml and its start working